# Spring+SpirngMVC+Hibernate configuration issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, transactions, web.xml

My purpose is to use transaction by annotation. But when I only use context-scan in `springmvc-servlet.xml`, the annotation transaction doesn't work. So I figured out that it should use spring framework to annotate the beans rather than spring-mvc. The spring-mvc is only to annotate controller. But when I start the server, it failed. Below is the error message.

Or how should I configure it to let it works with transaction by annotation?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.syxing.service.ContactService com.syxing.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.syxing.model.TblContactListDAO com.syxing.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.contactListDAO; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.syxing.model.TblContactListDAO field com.syxing.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.contactListDAO to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1260)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2002)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.syxing.service.ContactService com.syxing.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.syxing.model.TblContactListDAO com.syxing.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.contactListDAO; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.syxing.model.TblContactListDAO field com.syxing.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.contactListDAO to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.syxing.model.TblContactListDAO com.syxing.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.contactListDAO; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.syxing.model.TblContactListDAO field com.syxing.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.contactListDAO to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.syxing.model.TblContactListDAO com.syxing.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.contactListDAO; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.syxing.model.TblContactListDAO field com.syxing.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.contactListDAO to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set 

com.syxing.model.TblContactListDAO field com.sy
xing.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.contactListDAO to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    ... 41 more
```

The `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>syxing</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>   
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>   
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>  
  </context-param>
  <context-param>    
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>webApp.root</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>   
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>  
  </listener>


   <filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value> 
    </init-param>
    <!-- init-param>
      <param-name>singleSession</param-name>    
      <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param-->
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>csrfRequest</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.syxing.utils.RequestFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>csrfRequest</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>100000</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/resources/pages/404.html</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

And the whole `applicationContect.xml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.syxing" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url"
    value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/syxing?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:com/syxing/model/*.hbm.xml" />

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" 
   class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

`servletmvc-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- HandlerMapping -->
    <!-- bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" /-->
    <!-- HandlerAdapter -->
    <!-- bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" /-->

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.syxing.controller" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/app/" mapping="/app/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/json/" mapping="/json/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/html/" mapping="/html/**" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000" />
        <property name="resolveLazily" value="true" />
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="4096" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/> 
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: can you show us your bean definitions? In particular TblContactListDAOImpl where this error is coming from

Comment: I use the annotation to define the bean.

Comment: I use the annotation to define the bean. And when only use context-scan in springmvc-servlet.xml, there are no errors. When I use context-scan in both applicationContext.xml and springmvc-servlet.xml, it shows the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In your `applicationContext.xml` context file you are scanning everything including your controller sub-package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.syxing" />
```

Explicitly exclude the controller package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.syxing">
   <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.syxing\.controller\.*">
</context:component-scan>
```

In your `servletmvc-servlet.xml` context you are correctly scanning the `controller` package.

Don't forget: `servletmvc-servlet.xml` is the servlet context (child context) that can see your application context `applicationContext.xml` (parent context) but not the other way around.

Comment: I tried, when start the server,it still shows the error message.